# Mule HTTP Request Response Code 400 with @ symbol in URL

Tags: http, request, mule, http-status-code-400

** Question taken back **

I am using the HTTP:Request component in Mule 3.8 -

```
<http:request config-ref="httpRequestConfig" host="hostname" port="8081" path="validate/john.doe@gmail.com" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP Request" />
```

The HTTP Request Config looks like this -

```
<http:request-config name="httpRequestConfig" basePath="user" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration" />
```

This results in a response code of 400 -

```
Root Exception stack trace:
org.mule.module.http.internal.request.ResponseValidatorException: Response code 400 mapped as failure.
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.request.SuccessStatusCodeValidator.validate(SuccessStatusCodeValidator.java:37)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.request.DefaultHttpRequester.validateResponse(DefaultHttpRequester.java:356)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.request.DefaultHttpRequester.innerProcess(DefaultHttpRequester.java:344)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.request.DefaultHttpRequester.processBlocking(DefaultHttpRequester.java:217)
```

If I access the URL (http://hostname:8081/user/validate/john.doe@gmail.com) from Chrome, it works fine.

I know it is the @ symbol that is causing the issue. For a value without the @ symbol, the Mule flow works fine.

What could I be missing on the request?

Thanks for the help

Comment: My bad ! I had a catch-exception-strategy in my flow that was transforming the response from the service. The Mule flow was indeed behaving just like how it was behaving from Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL has to be encoded for special characters. For your case replace @ character with %40 like this http://hostname:8081/user/validate/john.doe%40gmail.com

It works for me, here is my code.

```
<http:listener-config port="8081" name="config" host="0.0.0.0" />

<flow name="test">
    <http:listener path="/Test/{emailAddress}" config-ref="config" />
    <logger level="INFO" message="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.uri.params'.emailAddress]"/>
</flow>
```

URL to test - http://localhost:8081/Test/senthil.test%40gmail.com

Comment: Thanks for the response. But, I get the same error with %40 instead of @.

Comment: Edited my answer above